# Divide two count from two queries result in sql in Jazz reporting service(JRS)

Tags: sql

I have two queries that will return two counts ,first query will return total number of defects and second query will return total number of test cases, I want to divide two queries for defect density(total number of defects/total number of test cases)
anyone can please to divide two queries?

```
SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T1.PROJECT_ID = 3)  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Defect' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL)GROUP BY T1.PROJECT_NAME,
         T1.REQUEST_TYPE //here is my first query
================================================================================
SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
FROM RIDW.VW_TESTCASE T1
WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T1.PROJECT_ID = 3) 
 AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.TESTCASE_ID <> -1 AND T1.TESTCASE_ID IS NOT NULL)GROUP BY 
T1.PROJECT_NAME //here is my second query

Thank you in Advance.
```

Comment: What prevent you from `SELECT (first query) / (second query)`?

Comment: @qxg Check the `WHERE` condtions, they're not quite the same.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, first query has nothing to do with second query. They can be arbitrary queries.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. The answer may depent on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT (CAST(a.REFERENCE_ID1 AS FLOAT) / CAST(b.REFERENCE_ID2 AS FLOAT )) AS REF_ID
FROM
(SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       T1.REQUEST_TYPE,
       COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID1
FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T1.PROJECT_ID = 3)  AND
(  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Defect' 
) AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL)GROUP BY T1.PROJECT_NAME,
         T1.REQUEST_TYPE

)a,

(SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME,
       COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID2
FROM RIDW.VW_TESTCASE T1
WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T1.PROJECT_ID = 3) 
 AND
(T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
(T1.TESTCASE_ID <> -1 AND T1.TESTCASE_ID IS NOT NULL)GROUP BY T1.PROJECT_NAME
)b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use both queries as derived tables and join them together based on `PROJECT_NAME` field:

```
SELECT r1.PROJECT_NAME, r1.REQUEST_TYPE, 
       r1.REFERENCE_ID / r2.REFERENCE_ID
FROM (
   SELECT T1.PROJECT_NAME, 'Defect' AS REQUEST_TYPE,
          COUNT( DISTINCT T1.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
   FROM RIDW.VW_REQUEST T1
   WHERE (T1.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T1.PROJECT_ID = 3)  AND
         (  T1.REQUEST_TYPE = 'Defect' ) AND
         (T1.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
         (T1.REQUEST_ID <> -1 AND T1.REQUEST_ID IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY T1.PROJECT_NAME) AS r1
JOIN (
   SELECT T2.PROJECT_NAME,
          COUNT( DISTINCT T2.REFERENCE_ID) AS REFERENCE_ID
   FROM RIDW.VW_TESTCASE T2
   WHERE (T2.PROJECT_ID = 1 OR T2.PROJECT_ID = 3) AND
         (T2.ISSOFTDELETED = 0) AND
         (T2.TESTCASE_ID <> -1 AND T2.TESTCASE_ID IS NOT NULL)
   GROUP BY T2.PROJECT_NAME
) AS r2 ON r1.PROJECT_NAME = r2.PROJECT_NAME
```

**Note:** I removed grouping by `REQUEST_TYPE` in the first subquery as this value is always set to the value specified in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: it show the  message like No results found. Please make sure you have access to the project(s) that contain the data you are looking for...